# Struts2 and Jetty welcome-file-lists

Tags: struts2, jetty

I am trying to get a Struts2 webapp and Jetty to play well. For some reason with Struts interceptors and FilterDispatcher configured my welcome file never get picked up I always encounter a 404. I have index.jsp in my webapp but for some reason when accessing http://localhost/webapp I always encounter 404.

For now I have set default-action-ref to my index.jsp in struts.xml but this means even for really non-existent files the user would get redirected to the index page. Is there a cleaner way to ensure Jetty picks up the welcome file? The welcome file gets picked up if the struts FilterDispatcher is **not** used, so I reckon it has got something to do with the way struts is configured?

The web.xml is a fairly standard web.xml with nothing fancy(?!). As I said earlier, I suspect it has got something to do with the struts.xml configuration.

struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.serve.static" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.codebehind.pathPrefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
<constant name="struts.configuration.classpath.defaultParentPackage" value="cms-default"/>
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory"/>
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="cms-messages,cms-version"/>
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="31457280"/>

<package name="cms-default" extends="codebehind-default">

    <interceptors>

        <interceptor-stack name="cmsStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="cmsStack" />
    <default-action-ref name="index"></default-action-ref>

    <global-results>
        <result name="redirectToUrl" type="redirect">${redirectedToURL}</result>
    </global-results>

    <action name="index">
        <result>/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

FWIW, The problems I am encountering are almost the same ones mentioned in [this](http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.jetty.user/msg/4A9E1B5C.6060506@gmail.com) email thread.

**Updated** With more information about the setup. Yeah the name webapp was just an example :)

Comment: You should post your web.xml. Do you get any errors during Jetty startup? And this might be a silly question, but is your war file/folder called webapp?

Comment: You say _"with Struts interceptors and FilterDispatcher configured my welcome file never get picked up"_ - does that mean it works fine without the struts components configured? If so, then we'll need to see how you configured them, because it seems that they're the source of problems. If you haven't tried that, then perhaps you should try setting up a welcome file with just the most simple webapp you can, so you can eliminate any other possible causes.

Comment: Updated my question with more info!

Comment: Please post the section of your `web.xml` that configures the struts FilterDispatcher. Since you've said that it works when that it removed, it would be helpful to see how it has been configured.